# how to migrate heroku file storage to S3

Tags: heroku, paperclip

I am an idiot, and very new to Heroku.  I used the heroku file system to store paperclip attached files to my models.

Have I lost these files?  And can I unload them to S3 somehow and have better access?

Its a low traffic site but its causing problems as it should for me to have it setup to store locally on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can assume you've lost the files - if the app has been restarted/scaled/deployed to then they'll have gone.

You'll want to get it setup to save the files to S3 in the future.

Comment: so every time i pushed to it, it wiped them all?

Comment: yep. The file system isn't persisted. When you push code it is compiled into a slug which is then deployed to the Heroku platform. Each new dyno you add copies the original slug so you'll end up with slugs with uploads in and others without. When you push again your app is compiled to a new slug....wiping out your old uploads.

Comment: i dont think that heroku will allow you to save files on their file system (other thatn db) its readonly copy. so after uploading you need to transfer them to third party storage like s3.

Comment: You can save files (/tmp on Bamboo and anywhere on Cedar stack applications) but the filesystem is not persisted.